# How would i move navbar elements to the left side, except the "Account" element of the navbar, and put it to the right side?

Tags: html, css

How would i go on about keeping every navbar element on the left side, except the "Account" element and put it to the right side, css is

```
body {
    font-family: 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
}

.navmenu {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(28, 83, 231);
    justify-content: left;
}

.navmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.navmenu > ul > li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
    color: rgb(119, 151, 240);
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.navmenu > ul > li:not(:hover) {
    transform: scale(1);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    transition: 0.4s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .navmenu > ul > li {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-right: 33px;
    }
}
```

html is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/design.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0;">
        <div class="navmenu">
            <ul style="list-style: none;" class="nav">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Purchase</li>
                <li><a>Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle if needed: 
`https://jsfiddle.net/56qtnu0c/` Help would be appreciated, i don't know how to do this, also if you could do it for me and tell me what i did wrong, that would be cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U need put account item to other ul like

```
 <div class="navmenu">
        <ul style="list-style: none;" class="nav">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Purchase</li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="list-style: none;" class="nav">
            <li><a>Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

then your navmenu class `justify-content: space-between;`

```
.navmenu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(28, 83, 231);
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot put your element that to be positioned differently in a single ul tag however you can achieve this using position absolute and all but will not be responsive. I did a few corrections like separating the account section and added few extra lines of CSS code to make the account always appear at the top right of the navigation bar. Hope this will resolve your problem.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
}

.navmenu {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(28, 83, 231);
}

.navmenu > ul{
flex-basis: 80%
}



.navmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.navmenu > ul > li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
    color: rgb(119, 151, 240);
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.navmenu > ul > li:not(:hover) {
    transform: scale(1);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.navmenu .account{
  list-style: none;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

.navmenu .account li{
  float: right
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .navmenu > ul > li {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-right: 33px;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/design.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0;">
        <div class="navmenu">
            <ul style="list-style: none;" class="nav">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Purchase</li>
            </ul>
            
            <ul class='account'>
             <li><a>Account</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```